# Compare 2 rows in different tables and update if similar

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I need advice with regards to the topic title. I have a query which compares two tables.
Table animal and table mammal. Now my query will show all rows of animal which has not similar record in  mammal.

Here's my query

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT name, [group] FROM animal
 EXCEPT
 SELECT  name, [group] FROM mammal) x
```

**TABLE FOR ANIMAL**

[image]

AND **TABLE FOR MAMMAL**

[image]

When I run the query stated above here's the result

[image]

I want to reverse it and show monkey and dog instead of cat and I also want to update the status of monkey and god from NULL to 2.

Any advice on how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
select a.name,a.[group],2 as [status] from animal a
where exists(select * from mammal b where b.name = a.name and b.[group]=a.[group])
```

Comment: It worked but It just shows 2 as status it does not update the animal table and set the status to 2.

Comment: update animal a set a.[status] = 2
where exists(select * from mammal b where b.name = a.name and b.[group]=a.[group])

Comment: Wohoo....Thank you so much Sir....It worked....I also tried using the query you gave and make it a nested query. Thank you so much.

Comment: I will. Indeed I will. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM 

        (SELECT name, [group] FROM animal

        intersect

        SELECT name, [group] FROM mammal) x;
```